# Forcing a specific page to use HTTPS with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

In our application we have a payment page that we want to use SSL on because we are handling credit card information. We've already put in place rewrite rules for apache to redirect a request to the specific page to HTTPS -- which takes care of any direct requests to the payment page ( http://oursite.com/pay ).

However most navigation in our site is done via relative urls and `states` using [`ui-router`](http://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) in angularjs and we have found that apache does not catch these requests and so serves the page without SSL.

EX If a user clicks a link with `ui-sref='pay'` `ui-router` loads the template and refreshes the state -- at no point is a request made to the server for a new uri so apache can't redirect to https

**Is there a way to force ui-router(or angular in general) to force a state to use HTTPS without having to change all links to reload the entire site?**

Of course this may also be a shortcoming in our rewrite rules...Here's what we have so far

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /pay
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

The second set of rules is to enforce html5mode for our app.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is in place so that angular can fetch the payment template for the state without needing SSL. Is this okay?

Comment: but I need a solution for forcing https client-side as well!

Comment: What do you mean by `forcing https client-side`? You want to do this via JS instead of .htaccess?

Comment: If a user clicks a link with `ui-sref='pay'` `ui-router` loads the template and refreshes the state -- at no point is a request made to the server for a new uri so apache can't redirect to https. The rewrite rules cover cases where people go directly to `domain.com/pay` but not cases where ui-router handles navigation. I need to make ui-router redirect on the `pay` state to https. Either that or make all links to `/pay` absolute `hrefs` which I'd rather not do..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I had a similar problem, although was using $routeProvider in a SPA application. What I did was to enforce a redirect inside the controller:

```
var forceSSL = function () {
    if ($location.protocol() !== 'https') {
        $window.location.href = $location.absUrl().replace('http', 'https');
    }
};
forceSSL();
```

This though does reload all resources. However, this happens only once when switching to SSL mode.

Note, the function is actually in a service so can be called from anywhere.

I hope this helps.

Comment: We ended up implementing the whole site with SSL and used rewrite rules in htaccess but this would have worked! thanks!

Comment: `replace('http', 'https')` - I would advise to use with caution, since there might be multiple occurrences of 'http' string in the URL.

Comment: Actually in this particular case, replace will only happens for the first occurence of the 'http'. To happen globally, one way of doing it is $location.absUrl().replace(/http/g, 'https');

Comment: Great work! Just made a couple of tiny syntax fixes.