# AngularJS SSL .htaccess woes

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I'm trying to enable the use of SSL on my .htaccess file that has already been set up for html5Mode direct linking but it's always resulting in a redirect loop. The closest question I've found on stackoverflow is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689543/forcing-a-specific-page-to-use-https-with-angularjs) but even from here I can't figure it out (I'm new to htaccess files).

AngularJS html5Mode direct linking htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

and this works perfectly. Explanation [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode).

Forcing SSL htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

and this also works by itself but when trying to combine them (forcing SSL before routing through index.html) it results in a redirect loop. If I had to guess it would be because it first redirects to using https and then the second redirect routes through index.html using http again. However, I don't know how to test it or fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: As pointed out I should've included what I tried resulting in a loop.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Comment: Remove the second `RewriteEngine` directive and put the HTTPS redirect first. For clarity, can you show the complete `.htaccess` file that **doesn't work**? It's pointless showing two separate parts that you say aren't working when put together

Comment: Sorry, post has been edited. It's simply one appended to the other with the second RewriteEngine removed.

Comment: Try this method for your HTTP rewrite ~ https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

Comment: @Phil, been trying it and
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]`
isnt working, still a redirect loop. I think it's functionally the same as what I had originally.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in generating htaccess files, but I found a solution, which is working on my server.

Try this one:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/index.html [L]
```

It's forcing https and Angular's HTML5 mode is working well too. Don't forget to set up both http (port 80) and https (port 443) urls in your web server config file. Of course this angular code snippet is still really important:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Good luck, I hope I helped you!

Comment: I tried this and did not work. Here's my .htaccess without the forceful https redirect:
`code`RewriteEngine On

Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]